# Cross domain windows authentication SSMS Error SQL Server 2012 - pre-login handshake failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to achieve cross domain windows authentication access to SQL Server database. I am logged in locally as ABC\user, and SQL Server db is allowing access for XYZ\user. I tried to follow the instructions in the following link, in order for me to access the db without having to do remote desktop.

http://www.olegsych.com/2009/05/crossing-domain-boundaries-windows-authentication/

However, when I open SSMS locally and connect to db server using windows authentication, it gives me a pre-login handshake error. Please see the error image below.

[Prelogin Handshake Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeFiv.jpg)

Here are the things that I have troubleshooted:

1) Make sure that firewalls are all off.

2) Make sure that the network is not blocking traffic to and fro.

3) In SQL Server Configuration Manager, under SQL Server Network Configuration, all IP Addresses in TCP/IP protocols are set to "YES" for Active and Enabled settings.

4) Check that my local computer is using IPv4 and IPv6 is DISABLED.

5) I am able to reach SQL Server locally when using SQL Authentication.

I would appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: Look at the windows logs of the SQL Server. My guess is that the SQL Server is not reaching the AD server.

Comment: in your point #5, youshould test using the domain account you are trying to connect with, and not SQL authentication.

Comment: Ricardo, Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ricardo, Thanks for the suggestion. 

In my point #5, I should have further clarified that I also have tested logging in to SQL Server db using Windows Authentication XYZ\User if I remote desktop to the db server.

I checked the Windows log, but I do not see any error messages being logged. Probably, I have filtered out the Source inaccurately as I just checked all the errors logged by SQL Server. Which other Source I should filter by?

In addition, I have checked the SQL Server Error log, but it also does not log any error about rejecting client connections.

Comment: I would check the Application and Security logs with no filtering and inspect any warning and error right at the time your connection fails. Now... you are saying you RDP... are you opening VPN tunnels?

Comment: ABC domain must be trusted domain in XYZ domain and user User exist.

Comment: Ricardo, I checked the Application and Security logs, but there are no warning or error messages right at the time my connection failed.

Yes, you are right. I open VPN tunnel to XYZ domain. So, when you do IPConfig, I have 2 IP Addresses; 1 pointing to ABC domain, and another to XYZ domain.

Comment: Alex Kudryashev, how to make sure that ABC domain is trusted in XYZ domain?

Comment: @Antony domain trust is set in the domain controller. Never implemented it myself.

Answer (score 0):

As a consultant I got the same problem with both of my clients.
I've solved it by creating a .bat script with the following line. Just adapt it to your SSMS directory and user account.

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\username "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
```

Comment: Zirxo, Thank for the reply.

Yes. I used the RUNAS to open up my SSMS, but it failed to log in my windows domain XYZ credentials.

Comment: Did you change the "/user:domain\username" part to your domain and username? And did you type the correct password in the command prompt?